# Swift 3 setValuesForKeys Error

Tags: swift, dictionary, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Im trying to get data from a dictionary and appending it in a array (I followed this [Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tv5c1mZttVE)).

This how the dictionary Looks like:

```
["Name": TEST, "ID": 51C3EE09-5718-4E07-9C88-FC2409BA6AC1, "Name_O": test, "Users": ]
```

but unfortunatly it fails to get the data

```
refHandle = ref.child("Pages").observe(.childAdded , with: { (snapshot) in
        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {

            print(dictionary)

            let data = Data()

            data.setValuesForKeys(dictionary) //Error Happens Here "Thread Breakpoint"
            self.dataList.append(data)

            self.tableView.reloadData()

        }
    })
```

If I remove the line where the error was the array would look something like this:

```
[<app.Data: 0x786f4830>, <app.Data: 0x786f4ef0>]
```

Which confuses me...

instead of typing `setValuesForKeys` appenrently it supposed to be written `setValuesForKeysWithDictionary` (in Tutorial) but does not work anymore.

Thanks in advance for helping!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38154998/2019221

Comment: But why does "setValuesForKeysWithDictionary" does not exist in anymore in swift 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Swift 3.0, it is now setValuesForKeys(_:)
https://developer.apple.com/reference/objectivec/nsobject/1417515-setvaluesforkeyswithdictionary?language=objc

Swift is now open sourced and the community I suppose decided that instance method is unnecessarily long.